# ¿Como borrar el lienzo de un solo contexto de canvas sin que se borren todos?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Estoy intentando cerar varias lineas en un canvas,para ser exacto 14 lineas,
estoy usando 14 contextos asi:

```
canvasL2V3 = document.getElementById("canvasL2V3");
ctx1 = canvasL2V3.getContext("2d");
ctx2 = canvasL2V3.getContext("2d");
ctx3 = canvasL2V3.getContext("2d");
ctx4 = canvasL2V3.getContext("2d");
ctx5 = canvasL2V3.getContext("2d");
ctx6 = canvasL2V3.getContext("2d");
ctx7 = canvasL2V3.getContext("2d");
ctx8 = canvasL2V3.getContext("2d");
ctx9 = canvasL2V3.getContext("2d");
ctx10 = canvasL2V3.getContext("2d");
ctx11 = canvasL2V3.getContext("2d");
ctx12 = canvasL2V3.getContext("2d");
ctx13 = canvasL2V3.getContext("2d");
ctx14 = canvasL2V3.getContext("2d");
canvasL2V3.width  =1366;
canvasL2V3.height = 768;
```

Mas adelante tengo un evento mousemove que me trae el contexto al que debe hacerle el movimiento y crear la linea.

```
$scope.captureCoordinate=function($event){
  if($scope.firstSelect){

  var ctx="ctx"+contexto;

    eval(ctx+'.clearRect(0, 0,'+canvasL2V3.width+','+canvasL2V3.height+');');//se limpia todo lo del contexto

    eval(ctx+'.beginPath();');
    eval(ctx+'.lineWidth = "1";');
    eval(ctx+'.strokeStyle = "purple";'); // Purple path
    eval(ctx+'.moveTo('+$scope.left+','+$scope.top+');'); // Purple path
    eval(ctx+'.lineTo('+$event.clientX+','+$event.clientY+');'); // Purple path
    eval(ctx+'.stroke();'); // Draw it


  }
}
```

ya esta validado que toma el contexto correcto,ya que son variables globales de mi js.
El problema es que al crear la linea siempre primero borro el contexto y marco la ultima posicion que dejó,y esta bien,a la hora de marcar la segunda linea,o el segundo contexto(ctx2).

```
ctx2.clearRect(0, 0,canvasL2V3.width,canvasL2V3.height);
```

el problema es que no borra el lienzo de ese contexto sino que borra todos;
como hago para limpiar el dibujo de cada contexto(ctx1,ctx2,ctx3,ct4...) por separado sin que me vacíe todo?

Comment: Debería usar los métodos `beginPath`, `moveTo`, `lineTo` y `stroke` del contexto (objeto devuelto por el método `getContext('2d')` para dibujar las líneas en el lienzo.

Answer (score 0):

El comportamiento que estas buscando no es posible de implementar actualmente ya que cada elemento canvas solo contiene un objeto `CanvasRenderingContext2D`, por lo tanto llamar múltiples veces a la función `getContext('2d')` solo te devolverá el mismo contexto.

Puedes verificar la temática en la especificación de estándares HTML relacionados al contexto 2d [aquí](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#2dcontext).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas trabajar con varios elementos canvas a la vez necesitas organizarte mejor: La solución es crear una clase de objetos canvas, crear varias instancias y guardarlas en un array: `lienzos` - en este caso.
De esta manera no habrá ningún problema a la hora de borrar el lienzo.

Por favor lea los comentarios en el código.

```js
//el array de todos los lienzos
let lienzos = [];
// una clase de objetos
class Lienzo {
  constructor() {
    //el elemento canvas
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    // el contexto
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    //la anchura
    this.w = this.canvas.width = 150;
    //la altura
    this.h = this.canvas.height = 150;
    // agregar el canvas al DOM
    contenedor_lienzos.appendChild(this.canvas);
    // una variable que tu llamaste "scope" utilixada para dibujar las líneas
    this.scope = {
      left: Math.random() * this.w,
      top: Math.random() * this.h
    };
    // agregar un evento al canvas
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", evt => {
      let m = laPosicionDelRaton(this.canvas, evt);
      this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.w, this.h);
      this.draw(m);
    });
  }
  //dibujar una línea desde el "scope" hasta la posición del ratón
  draw(m) {
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = "purple";
    this.ctx.moveTo(this.scope.left, this.scope.top);
    this.ctx.lineTo(m.x, m.y);
    this.ctx.stroke();
  }
}

// crear los lienzos
for (let i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
  lienzos.push(new Lienzo());
}

//una función para detectar la posición del ratón 
function laPosicionDelRaton(canvas, evt) {
  let ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    //objeto
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  };
}
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid #d9d9d9;margin:.5em;}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor_lienzos"></div>
```

Comment: el problema e que mis lineas deben poder entre cruzarse

Comment: En este caso necesito ver un ejemplo completo y funcional, no solo fragmentos de código.